# Cannot read property 'url' of undefined error because I don't know how to handle 'keypress' events that don't have a match in the referenced object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm building a drum app (press a key, hear a sound) in React/ Redux and have most of the React/ Redux stuff worked out, and it all works except for when I press a key that's not one of the registered drum keys.

I understand why I'm getting the error, but I don't know how to get around it short of writing an action for each individual button. I know I could probably use an if else statement somewhere, but I'm not sure where in the structure that would work.

This is a link to the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/k29r3928z7 , and any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

This is the basics of the code that's having the problem:

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => drumKeyPress(drumObj.filter(obj => {return obj.keyCode === event.keyCode})[0].url));
  }
```

and

```
export const drumKeyPress = (url) => {
  const sound = new Audio(url);
  sound.play();

  return {
    type: 'TYPEHIT',
    url
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code always assumes that there will be at least one object returned from `.filter()`, but there won't be for inactive keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if you find an entry in the array corresponding to the key first. If you do, then you can call `drumKeyPress`.

```
handleKeyPress = (event) => {
  const drumKey = drumObj.find(obj => obj.keyCode === event.keyCode);

  if (drumKey) {
    drumKeyPress(drumKey.url);
  }
};

componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener('keypress', this.handleKeyPress);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  document.removeEventListener('keypress', this.handleKeyPress);
}
```

Comment: That worked! I figured setting the const would fail it, but I realize now it just sets it to null. What's the proper way to have the componentDidUnmount setup to avoid memory leaks?

Comment: Good to know, much appreciated!